# What is the opposite of antiparallel?

Tags: vectors, terminology

Is *parallel* really the opposite of *anti-parallel*? While

- *anti-parallel* indicates that two vectors are directed along the same line **and are pointing in opposite directions**

then it seems to me that

- *parallel* just indicates that two vectors are directed along the same line. But **not** necessary pointing the same way.

This might not be the actual, mathematical/geometric definition of *parallel* but it does seem to me that this is how the word is being used, to such an extent that e.g. a student at an exam or an engineer seeing such word would *not* think of the vectors as necessarily
pointing the same way as well.

If I am right in this, is there then a better term for the opposite of *anti-parallel* when I need to specifically indicate that

- two vectors are directed along the same line **and are pointing the same way**?

In my native Danish language we do have such a term: *ensrettet*, which directly translates to something like "*like-directed*", which is a more strict term than *parallel* (a word we also use in Danish). I am struggling to find a proper translation of this.

Comment: Mathematics is not a linguistic science. Defintion: parallel $\langle \vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle=\|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\,.$ Anti-parallel: same with a minus sign.

Comment: Well, it truly is a matter of convention/definition. As is the issue of whether $0$ is parallel to a nonzero vector.

Comment: Antiparallel is a relation between three lines and parallel is a relation between two lines. I don't think they're even comparable, let alone opposites.

Comment: I'd personally say $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ are parallel (since I view parallel as a property of vector spaces, I.E. the span of each vector), while $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ are both parallel and cooriented (since both have the same orientation in any choice of frame). Conventions will differ between authors, but should generally be clear from context.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen The word *cooriented* could be what I am looking for. Doesn't that imply parallelity as well? If so, then that might be the answer, although it might be a less-known term.

Comment: @Steeven If one adopts the definition I was using (oriented the same way in any frame) then yes: it implies parallel in the sense I gave, since any vectors which are not parallel can be made to be orthogonal via a change of coordinates. I should mention my convention is perhaps slightly less common, but having taught linear algebra multiple times I've only rarely come across the word parallel... Far more often one is discussing frames or frame bundles, in which case orienting two objects the same way (which is what the word *cooriented* should literally translate to) is a very common thing.

Comment: I would usually specify both parallel and cooriented though, as I'd fear the reader could interpret the orientations to agree only in a *specific* frame rather than in *all* frames. (Indeed, it's more common in my experience to choose a specific frame such that the objects at hand are oriented the same, rather than already having that property for all frames). Adding parallel removes any potential ambiguity. This is what I meant in a prior comment when I said different definitions between authors in math should be clear from context: a good author should include enough info to be unambiguous.